# How to check in both server-side and client-side scripts if we are in preview mode or deployed version

Tags: google-app-maker

In AppMaker:
Is there a way to make a difference between the app running in preview mode and the app running as a deployed version ?

Because my app is sending mails and is setting Apps scripts triggers but the config for those should be different in preview mode and deployed versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The preview is just another deployment. It has its own drive table. One option is to store your config in drive table.