# Distinguish between Preview/Publish or get Database Name

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there a way in App Maker to know if the Preview is running or if it is a Deployment? If not is there a server-side script that can get the Cloud SQL database name being used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppMaker: environment variables per deployment ? Get the deployment name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51627648/appmaker-environment-variables-per-deployment-get-the-deployment-name)